# php multiplication, it shows code when i press sumbit

Tags: php

I have been given an exercise to complete, in which I have to multiply two values.

HTML file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form action="multiplication.php" method="POST">
                <input type="text" size="4" id="A" name="A" />
                *
                <input type="text" size="4" id="B" name="B" />
                =
                <span id="answ">
                    <?php echo $equals; ?>
                </span>

                <input id="go" type="submit" value="submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

PHP file:

```php
<?php
include("form.php");
$A = $_POST['A'];
$B = $_POST['B'];

$equals = $A * $B;


?>
```

However, when I press the submit button, the PHP code is displayed, instead of the result.

Comment: Are you running the files through the PHP parser instead of using some local path e.g. `file://`?

Comment: Is the fileextenstion ".php"?

Comment: local path and yep they are php

Comment: You should run the files through PHP / your webserver. When you use a local path PHP never parses the script.

Comment: but the code looks ok?

Comment: Yes although I suspect you might want to `echo` the result at some point.

Comment: <span id="answ">
<?php echo $equals; ?>
</span>    this is nothing then?

Comment: You are doing the calculation after the echo. Also, is this just one script (multiplication.php)?

Comment: how to do it before then. I can only modify the php part as its an excerise. yes its only 1 script

Comment: try to place the php section top of your code before html tag

Comment: i can only edit this php file  <?php
include("form.php");
$A = $_POST['A'];
$B = $_POST['B'];
$equals = $A * $B;
?>

Comment: Vivek Muthal gave the right code but , but it gives this error and i cant get rid of it Notice: Undefined variable: equals in /form.php on line 15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the code should be like this. Assuming the file is multiplication.php

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
    $A = $_POST['A'];
    $B = $_POST['B'];

    $equals = $A * $B;
}
else
{
    $A=0;
    $B=0;
    $equals = 0;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<div>
<form action="multiplication.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" size="4" id="A" name="A" value = "<?php echo $A ?>"/>
*
<input type="text" size="4" id="B" name="B" value = "<?php echo $B ?>"/>
=
<span id="answ">
<?php echo $equals; ?>
</span>

<input id="go" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is it, but Notice: Undefined variable: equals in /form.php on line 15

Comment: change the form action to the name of your file, or save this code as multiplication.php, $equals is defined on top.

Comment: negative vote? why? it's working code.

Comment: i didint give negative. it is working and thank you

Comment: thanks you for selecting as correct answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Php is server side scripting language, it cannot run in the browser. The server interprets it and generates html. You need to set up a web server with php module (apache for example) and load the webpage from there.

Answer (score -1):

You can finish off this in one script instead of doing tedious tasks between two scripts.

Make sure the `values` are posted with `isset` (whether variables are defined)

Use `isset($_POST['A'])`, etc.. for making sure they are posted indices are set.

And when echoing `$equals`, check it is calculated using `isset($equals)`. Understand the flow by the example given below.

It seems you have trouble with passing back the values between the pages. Understand how they are processed by reading good tutorials.

Corrected version: multiplications.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['A'])&&isset($_POST['B'])){
            $A = $_POST['A'];
            $B = $_POST['B'];

            $equals = $A * $B;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<div>
<form action="multiplications.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" size="4" id="A" name="A" />
*
<input type="text" size="4" id="B" name="B" />
=


<span id="answ">

<?php 
    if(isset($equals))
        echo $equals; 

?>
</span>

<input id="go" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you still want two scripts you can just include the `form.php` after calculation part of `multiplication.php`.

Make sure you have this in `form.php`:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($equals))
        echo $equals; 
?>
```

And make your `multiplication.php` include this:

```
<?php

       if(isset($_POST['A'])&&isset($_POST['B'])){
        $A = $_POST['A'];
        $B = $_POST['B'];

        $equals = $A * $B;
       }

      include "form.php";
  ?>
```

Comment: problem is you are changing first file too and i was allowed to change only php file. Allthough your code works, i cant use it. Thank  you for u answer. sadly i cant upvote. I didint downvote cuz i cant i need 125 rep

Comment: in my edit I changed it to multiplications.php :)                   the other two code fragments are only advice.. first one will work....in first edit also....that's a matter of changing filename and action attribute....

Comment: I see.i'd upvote but i cant. i dont have rep. all i can do is say thanks!

Comment: no problem....get going....you can come back and vote later..... best of luck]